Does Spring support @Value on superclass?
I am having trouble finding a definitive answer whether Spring @Value annotations work on super-class / are inherited.
class Base {

    @Value("${app.some.property:hello}")
    private String someProperty;

    protected String getSomeProperty(){
        return someProperty;
    }
}

class MyClass extends Base {
    @Value("${app.other.property:world}")
    private String otherProperty;

    @PostConstruct
    void init(){
        System.out.println(getSomeProperty() + " " + otherProperty);
    }
}

will this yield hello world?

While this does not seem to be documented, it does work.
I debugged around and found the place in Spring Framework (V6.1.6) source code that checks all super-classes for injectable fields in
AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#buildAutowiringMetadata.
    private InjectionMetadata buildAutowiringMetadata(Class<?> clazz) {

        // [...]

        final List<InjectionMetadata.InjectedElement> elements = new ArrayList<>();
        Class<?> targetClass = clazz;

        do {
            // [...]
            targetClass = targetClass.getSuperclass();
        }
        while (targetClass != null && targetClass != Object.class);

        return InjectionMetadata.forElements(elements, clazz);
    }

